# Mac OS X: How do you set ipfw rules on startup?

Tags: macos, mac, launchd, ipfw

How do you apply a list of ipfw rules at startup on Mac OS X?

i.e. I have a list of rules like these that I'm applying manually.

```
sudo ipfw add 00100 ...
sudo ipfw add 00101 ...
sudo ipfw add 00102 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right your rules into a shell script and then create a [launchd plist](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html) to fire off the script at boot.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a tool like [NoobProof or WaterRoof](http://www.hanynet.com/applications/index.html) to set the rules up and save them in a startup configuration.